# Regex.Split Unity3d

Tags: arrays, regex, string, unity-game-engine, split

I'm tryin to make a string array using Regex.Split and this pattern: `(?s)(?=label).+?(?=label)` 
Tested in [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

[image]

I want to fill an array with chunks of text between the words 'label',
The block of text I'm trying to break up is a bit like:

*label 1
bla bla bla
 #stuff stuff
more stuff

*label 2
da di da
  #dum de do
etc etc

*label 3
etc...

So ( as an example ) I want *BookData[0] =*

label 1
bla bla bla
 #stuff stuff
more stuff

*

I'm in Unity, I have `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` up top, and then I have:

```
string pattern = "(?s)(?=label).+?(?=label)";

    string[] BookData = Regex.Split(input,pattern);

    Debug.Log(BookData[0]);
```

I get no result, please help. ( many thanks )

Comment: in first instance, Change to `Debug(input +" " +BookData[0]);`

Comment: You need matching, not splitting, with this regex. If you can use LINQ, use `string[] BookData = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();`. I'd also suggest the [`(?s)\blabel\b(?:(?!\blabel\b).)*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)%5cblabel%5cb(%3f%3a(%3f!%5cblabel%5cb).)*&i=*label+1%0d%0abla+bla+bla%0d%0a%23stuff+stuff%0d%0amore+stuff%0d%0a%0d%0a*label+2%0d%0ada+di+da%0d%0a%23dum+de+do%0d%0aetc+etc%0d%0a%0d%0a*label+3%0d%0aetc...&o=s) regex.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Just use a verbatim string literal with my regex `@"(?s)\blabel\b(?:(?!\blabel\b).)*"`

Comment: Bingo Wiktor! works a treat. I added `using System.Linq;` and used the 'verbatim version of your pattern: `string pattern = @"(?s)\blabel\b(?:(?!\blabel\b).)*";`  and the main array: `string[] BookData = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();` If you put together an answer, I can accept it. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding `{using System.Linq;}`, use the following regex with a `Regex.Matches`:

```
@"(?s)\blabel\b(?:(?!\blabel\b).)*"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)%5Cblabel%5Cb(%3F%3A(%3F!%5Cblabel%5Cb).)%2A&i=%2Alabel%201%0D%0Abla%20bla%20bla%0D%0A%23stuff%20stuff%0D%0Amore%20stuff%0D%0A%0D%0A%2Alabel%202%0D%0Ada%20di%20da%0D%0A%23dum%20de%20do%0D%0Aetc%20etc%0D%0A%0D%0A%2Alabel%203%0D%0Aetc...&o=s)

Your code will look like:

```
string[] BookData = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
```

The regex matches:

- `(?s)` - enable single line mode when `.` matches a newline
- `\blabel\b` - match a whole word `label`
- `(?:(?!\blabel\b).)*` - match any character that is not a starting character of a `label` character sequence that is a whole word.

If you do not need to check for the whole word, remove `\b`s.